# How do you use the INSERT SQL statement in a Java JDBC program?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following code :

```
                try{    

                        String select2 =   "INSERT INTO employees VALUES (17, 'Adam', 'Kizzam', 'aa@zz.com', '123-456-7890', '12-DEC-00', '1234', '12345.23, 50', '12.25', 1222, 4769 ) ";

                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = connection.prepareStatement(select2); // dbConnection. prepareStatement(selectSQL);
                        ResultSet rs2 = preparedStatement2.executeUpdate(select2);

                        while (rs.next()) {
                          String userid = rs.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID");
                          String username = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
                          System.out.println ("the userid , username are " + userid + " " +  username);
                } }
```

This gives me the following error :

> Error(54,77): incompatible types;  required: java.sql.ResultSet; 
>   found:
>   int   DBConnection.java   C:\JDeveloper\mywork\OracleDatabaseApp\OracleDatabaseApp\src\oracledatabaseapp  OracleDatabaseApp.jpr

Comment: Please read the compiler error, and check the return types shown by your IDE or the Javadoc before posting a question like this. This is basic Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) returns an int

```
int rows = preparedStatement2.executeUpdate(select2);
```